# How can I disable script in runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I have a problem, it is that gameobject.enabled does not work, and I tried everything but I can not solve it, I would appreciate very much if you help me. Here are the scripts I wrote:

[image]
[image]

Beforehand, thank you very much.

Here the code:

```
public class GenerarCartaAleatoria : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject go, padre;
    
    string numSprite;
    int contador = 1;
    int contadorChild;
    int contadorOrder = 329;

    public void Generar()
    {
        string numRandom = Random.Range(1,36).ToString();
        int numLenght = numRandom.Length;

        if (numLenght == 1)
        {
            numSprite = "Sprites/000" + numRandom;
        }
        else if(numLenght == 2)
        {
            numSprite = "Sprites/00" + numRandom;
        }
        else if (numLenght == 3)
        {
            numSprite = "Sprites/0" + numRandom;
        }
        else if (numLenght == 4)
        {
            numSprite = "Sprites/" + numRandom;
        }

        GameObject spriteCosa = Instantiate(go);

        spriteCosa.transform.parent = padre.transform;

        GameObject cosasa = transform.GetChild(contadorChild).gameObject;

        cosasa.AddComponent<Image>();

        cosasa.GetComponent<GenerarCartaAleatoria>().enabled = false;

        cosasa.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
        
        cosasa.name = contador.ToString();

        cosasa.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(numSprite);

        cosasa.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(1,1,0);

        cosasa.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(-171, contadorOrder, 0);

        contador++;
        contadorChild++;
        contadorOrder += 100;
    }
}
```

My hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: We can't debug images of code. Please edit your question to actually provide the code in text form.

Comment: Just a side note. It is considered a bad practice to use non English naming in code. It makes it much more difficult for others to understand the intention of the code.

Comment: Nikkas, thanks for the advice

Comment: DON'T use the `script` tag. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. It's no better than adding `code` as a tag. That tag is just noise, it was deleted in the past and will be deleted very soon again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to disable a GameObject, the use is `gameObejct.SetActive(bool)` where bool is either true or false. To turn it off, the line would be `yourGameObjectHere.SetActive(false)` or in your case, `cosas.SetActive(false)`.

I am a bit confused with the wording of your question though. You wrote gameObject.enabled does not work. Do you mean that the .enabled is not working on your component? When you use the .enable it is used on a component-wise basis, so it would be disabling the component called `GenerarCartaAleotoria` on the gameObject you are finding. Is this .enabled = false not working and that is your question?

Comment: TEEBQNE Yes, i'm trying to disable a component, sorry for my bad writing

Comment: No worries just wanted to clarify. Two questions: 1. Are you sure you are grabbing the right GameObject with the GetChild? and 2. Are there any errors of a null reference when you get to the GetComponent line?

Comment: Llama, done, edit the question and put the code.

Comment: TEEBQNE, no, there is none of that

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with your code? From what I see you are randomly generating a number from 1->35 and converting it to a string then based on that length, setting a Resource sting reference to a sprite. After this, you are instantiating a prefab called go and setting its parent to padre. Then you are getting the child of the script the object is on at the child index of contradorChild. After this you set various data on this object then increment your counters. I believe you are getting the wrong object with your GetChild which is causing the issue.

Comment: What I am finding odd is you are using the script that spawns these objects, then attempting to get this script on what you just spawned and disabling that. Does this new object also have this spawner script on it too? Or do you just want to disable the script that is spawning the objects?

Comment: I am trying to disable the script that generates the objects.

Comment: When do you want to disable it? Right after one object is spawned? If that's the case, instead of your current GetComponent.enabled line, just use `this.enabled = false`

Comment: I am trying to disable the script of the generated objects, since the generated objects have a copy of that script to delete

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is the object you are spawning `spriteCosa` different from the reference object you are grabbing `cosasa`? Can you post what your hierarchy looks like as an image? I can not quite understand what you are trying to achieve with the code given you are spawning an object from an object that has the same script.

Comment: Edit the question and put a picture of my hierarchy

Comment: no, it isn't, but don't worry anymore, I already solved it by moving a few things in the script

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I am still not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve by spawning an object that spawns exactly itself. In cases like this, I would make a manager that spawns the objects then a prefab of the object that it can spawn.